# Can someone explain this Prolog code

Tags: list, prolog

```
aminoseq(X) :-
   aminoseq(X, []).

aminoseq([], X) :-
   print(X).
aminoseq([A|B], X) :-
   aminotodna(A, Y),
   append(X, Y, Z),
   aminoseq(B, Z).
```

This Prolog code allows the user to enter in a list and combines that list with a preset aminotodna list and displays both of the results. I don't understand which part does what... I'd like to know for future work.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First off, `aminoseq/1` invokes `aminoseq/2`, implying that the second argument to `aminoseq/2` is some sort of state variable whose initial value is the empty list.

Next, `aminoseq/2` is recursively processing the first argument, which is a list. When the list becomes empty (I assume it's a list of amino acids or something) it just prints the second argument. That's the first clause of `aminoseq/2`.

Next, the second clause of `aminoseq/2`. It tries to convert the amino acid `A` (the current first item in the first argument list) into something else (DNA, I guess) and calls it `Y`. Then it appends `X` (the current "state" argument) to `Y` giving `Z`, which it then recurs on with the remaining items in the list of arguments.

I don't know a lot about biology, but I can guess that what's intended to happen here is that you want to pass in a list of amino acids and get back a list of DNA bases. This is not a spectacularly efficient approach (in particular, I kind of hate that you print at the end of `aminoseq/2`) but it will do the task. I would recommend that you examine the output using `trace/0` to see what Prolog is trying to do as you go.

What part is doing what? All of the real work is being done in `aminotodna/2` which is the actual table that goes from amino acids to codons. The rest of this code is just managing the data structure, the lists.

I would approach the problem more like this:

```
amino_dna(gly, [g,g,g]).
amino_dna(gly, [g,g,a]).
% ...
amino_dna(lys, [a,a,g]).
% ...
amino_dna(ser, [t,c,g]).
amino_dna(pro, [c,c,c]).

amino_acid_dna_sequence([], []).
amino_acid_dna_sequence([Acid|Acids], [C1,C2,C3|DNA]) :-
    amino_dna(Acid, [C1,C2,C3]),
    amino_acid_dna_sequence(Acids, DNA).
```

I find this a bit more direct: less `append/3` banging around and no intermingling of I/O with logical relationships. And it can be driven in both directions:

```
?- amino_acid_dna_sequence([lys,ser,pro], X).
X = [a, a, g, t, c, g, c, c, c].

?- amino_acid_dna_sequence([lys,gly,pro], X).
X = [a, a, g, g, g, g, c, c, c] ;
X = [a, a, g, g, g, a, c, c, c].

?- amino_acid_dna_sequence(Aminos, [a,a,g,t,c,g,c,c,c]).
Aminos = [lys, ser, pro] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Daniel wrote (+1), I have the following two minor points:

1. remove the `_to_` from relation names. Since a pure relation can be used in all directions, it does not make sense to use a name that implies a direction.
2. always consider using [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) when describing lists. They often make your code a lot easier to read since they require fewer arguments and variable names.

I therefore suggest:

```
amino_dna(gly) --> [g,g,g].
amino_dna(gly) --> [g,g,a].
% ...
amino_dna(lys) --> [a,a,g].
% ...
amino_dna(ser) --> [t,c,g].
amino_dna(pro) --> [c,c,c].

amino_sequence([]) --> [].
amino_sequence([Acid|Acids]) -->
    amino_dna(Acid),
    amino_sequence(Acids).
```

Sample query:

```
?- length(Ls, _), phrase(amino_sequence(As), Ls).
As = Ls, Ls = [] ;
As = [gly],
Ls = [g, g, g] ;
As = [gly],
Ls = [g, g, a] ;
As = [lys],
Ls = [a, a, g] ;
As = [ser],
Ls = [t, c, g] ;
etc.
```

Notice the use of `length/2` for fair enumeration.

Comment: I wish I had thought of that!